# Are there more C# questions on SO because it's used more, or because it's more difficult /confusing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why so many questions tagged C# on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/why-so-many-questions-tagged-c-on-stackoverflow)

Are there more C# questions on Stack Overflow because it's used more, or because it's more difficult /confusing?

Comment: Qualification: It's used more by people that use this site. More C# people use this site because more C# content is available. It's a vicious cycle.

Comment: @Anthony - or virtuous, depending on how you look at it ;)

Comment: It is a matter of the population, like Anthony said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the developers of SO are from the .net community.

Comment: To the extent that their blog followers came here in large numbers, yes. However, the technology behind the site doesn't impact the people who visit it. For all I know, they've secretly switched from ASP.NET MVC to PHP.

Answer (score 4):

There are more C# questions here because there are more C# answers here.

Comment: That makes my head hurt...

Comment: There are more C# answers because there are more C# people. And there are more C# people...

Answer (score -1):

More and more people are choosing C# as a primary development platform, plus its a fantastic language and technology, so there is lots of questions!

Comment: You sound like a marketing drone.